# Syntax Error in Factoring Trinomial code Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm making a program to automatically factor trinomials but when ever I run the code i get this

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)
```

Can someone help?

```
B = prompt("B=?")
C = prompt("C=?")
X = C - 2C
Y = C / X

while(X + Y !== B)
{
  X + 1 ;
}  

alert(X)
alert(Y)
```

Comment: `2C` isn't a valid variable name, are you trying to multiply `C` by 2? if so it would be `(2*C)`

Comment: The `while` will be an endless loop. It has to be `X = X + 1` or `X++`